# Preserving linebreaks in the begginning of textarea

Tags: php, html, textarea, newline

Here again with new problem

```
$a='
1
2
3
';
```

in textarea it displayed without the first new line.

```
<?php echo'<textarea>',$a,'</textarea>'; />
```

like this

```
----------------
1
2
3
----------------
```

but it should be like this?

```
----------------

1
2
3
----------------
```

PS
sorry for my English =)

Comment: On the browsers that I tested this (IE, Chrome, Firefox, Opera), this did not happen. An empty line in HTML source causes an empty line in rendering, as expected. Please specify the conditions where you tested this. Note that textarea is intended for user input, and if you have difficulties in using it for rendering content, you should probably consider some other approach (like a div element styled to be scrollable).

Comment: @Jukka K. Korpela It did in my Opera and IE. I dont know.

Comment: You have changed the question, and it now contains code that generates HTML code, instead of HTML as such. Which language is `echo`?

Comment: echo is PHP and so is the $variable syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the HTML decimal or hexadecimal code for carriage return instead of a space.

```
<textarea>
&#x0D;
1
2
3
</textarea>
```

Comment: An interesting side note: The textarea tag appears to ignore the first newline, but not the last newline. http://jsfiddle.net/BzgX7/ This seems wrong to me. It looks like browsers are compromising data integrity for the prettiness of a newline. I could understand the argument that all new tags should be on newlines. If that is the case, then the end new line should also be trimmed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to introduce a character the browser will render between lines, as an HTML parser will ignore normal whitespace characters. Namely: put a break (literally "<br>") tag between things you want on separate lines.

Comment: No, the very point of `textarea` is that it preserves line breaks.

Comment: Yes, it does, but when you re-display it, unless your server side has parsed your \r\n, \n\r, \n and \r characters to <br>s it's not going to display them correctly. Maybe I'm solving the wrong problem because of the spotty English; thought this was a textarea input -> display thing. Of course, that all depends on my interpretation of "it become to look like this" to mean some sort of intermediate processing.

Comment: @ jimcavoli  Thanx for your effort. I've improved my question. =)